# ListItem not showing information - React Native Elements

Tags: react-native, listitem

When I use  it works fine.
But when I try to use , nothing appears.

That's my code:

```
export default props => {
    //console.warn(Object.keys(props))
    function getUserItem({item: user}) {
        console.warn(user.name)
        return (
            <ListItem
                leftAvatar={{source: {uri: user.avatarUrl}}}
                key={user.id}
                title={user.name}
            />
        )
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={user=>user.id.toString()}
                data={users}
                renderItem={getUserItem}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Can anybody helps me? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
   ...
 </View>

 const getUserItem = ({item: user}) => {
       ...
 }
```